# if-statement in mybatis insert query

Tags: sql, if-statement, mybatis

I would like to know how can I put if-statement inside a insert SQL-query. I would like to insert two parameters (CODRIC and PROGRIC) only if they are not null. I write something like this

```
INSERT
        INTO
            ${schema}.I9TB1000
            (
                I9TB1000_PROGR,
                I9TB1000_DATARIF,
                I9TB1000_STATO,
                I9TB1000_STATOP,
                I9TB1000_FUNZ,
                I9TB1000_CODRIC,
                I9TB1000_PROGRIC,
                I9TB1000_INSMATR,
                I9TB1000_INSTERM
            )
            VALUES( 
                NEXT VALUE FOR ${schema}.I9TB001S,
                (SELECT
                    I9TB1000_DATARIF
                FROM
                    ${schema}.I9TB1000
                WHERE
                    I9TB1000_PROGR =
                    (
                        SELECT
                            MAX (I9TB1000_PROGR)
                        FROM
                            ${schema}.I9TB1000)),
                (   SELECT
                        COALESCE(I9TBFUNZ_STA_TO,#{i9TB1000_STATOP, jdbcType=INTEGER})
                    FROM
                        ${defaultSchema}.I9TBFUNZ
                    WHERE
                        I9TBFUNZ_FUNZ = #{i9TB1000_FUNZ, jdbcType=INTEGER} ), 
                #{i9TB1000_STATOP, jdbcType=INTEGER},
                #{i9TB1000_FUNZ, jdbcType=INTEGER},
                <if test="i9TB1000_CODRIC != null">
                    #{i9TB1000_CODRIC, jdbcType=CHAR},
                </if>
                <if test="i9TB1000_PROGRIC != null">
                    #{i9TB1000_PROGRIC, jdbcType=INTEGER},
                </if>
                #{insMatr, jdbcType=CHAR},
                #{insTerm, jdbcType=CHAR}
            )
```

I take error -117 THE NUMBER OF VALUES ASSIGNED IS NOT THE SAME AS THE NUMBER OF SPECIFIED OR IMPLIED COLUMNS. It seems that mybatis couldn't read the if-statements... Someone could explain me why?

 Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message says it all. The number of values does not match the number of columns to be inserted.
You need to add `if` to the list of columns as well:

```
INSERT INTO table (
      ... other columns ...,
      <if test="i9TB1000_CODRIC != null">
          I9TB1000_CODRIC,
      </if>
      <if test="i9TB1000_PROGRIC != null">
      I9TB1000_PROGRIC,
      </if>
      ... other columns ...
) VALUES (
     ... values ...
)
```